# how to get tables for deleted birds,animals, accessories

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am new to nodeJs and Express and want to get the details of the items that I'd deleted i.e, animals,birds,accessories

following below is my JavaScript code.

```
const { count } = require('console');
var express = require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
const { createConnection } = require('net');
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/public"))

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    database:'mini_project',
    password:'password'
});


app.get("/animals", function(req, res){
    var q="select animals.pet_id,pet_category,breed,weight,age,height,fur,cost from animals join pets on animals.pet_id= pets.pet_id";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("dogs_home",{data:results});
    
    });
});

app.get("/birds", function(req, res){
    var q="select birds.pet_id,type,noise,cost from birds join pets on birds.pet_id= pets.pet_id";
        connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("birds_home",{data:results});
    });
});


app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.render("home");

});

app.get("/accessories", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from pet_products";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("accessories",{data:results});
    
    });
});

app.get("/sales", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from sales_details";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("sales",{data:results});
    
    });
});

app.get("/customers", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from customer";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("customer",{data:results});
    
    });
});

app.get("/ani_add", function(req, res){
 
        res.render("ani_add");
    
});

app.get("/animal_id_add", function(req, res){
 
    res.render("animal_id_add");

});




app.post("/register_dogs",function(req,res){
    var dog={pet_id:req.body.pet_id,
             breed:req.body.breed,
             weight:req.body.weight,
             height:req.body.height,
             age:req.body.age,
             fur:req.body.fur};
    var q="insert into animals set ?"
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/animals");
});

});

app.post("/register_dogs_id",function(req,res){
    var dog={pet_id:req.body.pet_id,
             pet_category:req.body.pet_category,
             cost:req.body.cost};
    var q="insert into pets set ?"
    connection.query(q,dog,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect("/ani_add");
});

});


//route for delete data for dogs
app.post('/delete',(req, res) => {
    let query = "DELETE FROM pets WHERE pet_id=?";
    let values= [req.body.pet_id];
    connection.query(query, values, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect("/animals");
    });
});

//route for delete data for birds
app.post('/delete_birds',(req, res) => {
    let query = "DELETE FROM birds WHERE pet_id=?";
    let values= [req.body.bird_id];
    connection.query(query, values, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect("/birds");
    });
});

//route for delete data for customers
app.post('/delete_customer',(req, res) => {
    let query = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE cs_id=?";
    let values= [req.body.customer_id];
    connection.query(query, values, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect("/customers");
    });
});


app.post('/delete_pp_id',(req, res) => {
    let query = "DELETE FROM pet_products WHERE pp_id=?";
    let values= [req.body.pp_id];
    connection.query(query, values, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.redirect("/accessories");
    });
});


app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 8080!');
   });
```

I'd used the below code for getting the deleted items but every time I got redirected to wrong table.

```
app.get("/sold_products", function(req, res){
    var q="select * from sold_products join pet_products on sold_products.pp_id= pet_products.pp_id";
    connection.query(q,function(err,results){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render("accessories",{data:results});
    
    });
});
```

I'd already created a table called sold pets.

```
create table sold_pets(sd_id varchar(9) not null,
pet_id varchar(9) not null,
primary key(pet_id),
foreign key(sd_id)references sales_details(sd_id)on delete cascade, foreign key(pet_id)references pets(pet_id)on delete cascade);
```

Similarly for sold products.

```
create table sold_products(sd_id varchar(9) not null, pp_id varchar(9) not null,
quantity int(11) not null,
primary key(pet_id,pp_id),
foreign key(sd_id)references sales_details(sd_id)on delete cascade, foreign key(pp_id)references pet_products(pp_id)on delete cascade );
```

Comment: Are you sure the 'pet_products' records that you reference in 'sold_products.pp_id' still exist? By the code, i don't get how you can get 'redirected to the wrong table'.

May i ask, why don't you have one single 'animals' table with an 'animal_type_id' field, and an 'animal_types' table? You would not have to split almost identical data-structures across several tables.

I'd also consider not deleting (with DELETE) animal records, but having an ENUM field that allows an 'animal' of given 'animal_type_id' to be 'available', 'quarantined', 'sold', etc.

Also, take a look at sequelize.

Comment: What do you mean by 'deleted'?

Comment: by deleted I meant that I want to access those pets or accessories in table  which I had deleted from mySql table.